# How to get the count of number of sheets available in excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node module mongo-xlsx to parse excel file and convert the data into JSON format. The problem is i am not able to get the count of sheets available in Excel file. Is their any other possible way to get the count of sheets available??

```
        var fileXLS = req.body.fileXLS;

        var path = "./public/files/location/upload/" + date + ".xlsx";

        var flowController = new EventEmitter();

        // Initialize
        flowController.on('START', function () {

            (consoleLog) ? console.log('1') : '';

            require("fs").writeFile(path, fileXLS, 'base64', function (err) {
                if (err) {

                    res.json({message: 'CAN\'T INSERT INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, UNKNOWN SERVER ERROR HAS OCCURRED!!!!!' + err, status: 'error', statusCode: '500'});
                } else {

                    var model = null;

                    mongoXlsx.xlsx2MongoData(path, model, function (err, mongoData) {
                        if (err) {

                            flowController.emit('ERROR', {message: 'ERROR WHILE UPLOADING EXCEL FILE ' + err, status: 'error', statusCode: '500'});
                        } else {

                            flowController.emit('2', mongoData);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code? I've had a quick look at the source and it looks like it's based off [node-xlsx](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx) package which should return an object per sheet.

Comment: @James I have updated the code. You can check it in the flow emitter segment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/Moblox/mongo-xlsx/blob/master/lib/mongo-xlsx.js#L309), there should be a 3rd parameter which returns the list of sheet names e.g.

```
mongoXlsx.xlsx2MongoData(path, model, function(err, data, names) {
    console.log('Sheet names', names);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the output of JSON from excel object i found the solution which is pretty much simple to even understand...

When you convert the Object into JSON array then if your excel file have more than one sheets, it creates that much number of arrays inside the main array which i called as `mongoData` in my piece of code.

The solution is

```
mongoXlsx.xlsx2MongoData(path, model, function (err, mongoData) {

 console.log('Number of sheets: '+mongoData.length);

 if(mongoData.length !== 1){
  //Error
  }else{
  //Further logic
  }
});
```